# Каков диапазон распределения функции randn()?

Tags: python, pytorch

В библиотеке для машинного обучения `pytorch` есть функция создания массива заполненного случайными числами нормального распределения.

Называется это функция `randn()`. Она на вход принимает обязательный аргумент `size`. Аргумент `size` может быть целым числом или кортежем (`shape` массива в случае кортежа, и одномерный массив в случае целого числа).

В официальной документации не нашел размер распределения. То есть, из какого диапазона выбираются эти случайные числа - границы диапазона?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> то есть из какого диапазона выбираются эти случайные числа - границы диапазона?

**Ни каких (теоретических) границ нету.**

Но практически (почти) все числа будет из интервала **(-3, 3)** - см. дальше.

Выбор случайных чисел функцией `randn()` такой, чтобы следовал (приблизительно) нормальное распределение с математическим ожиданием 0 и стандартным отключением 1.

Значит, для [неравенства Чебышёва](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) будет более чем

- 50% из них в интервале (-1, 1),
- 75% из них в интервале (-2, 2),
- 89% из них  в интервале (-3, 3).

Но для [неравенства Высочанского — Петунина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0):

- вероятность падения в интервал **(-3, 3)** приблизительно ровна даже **99.73 %**.

Answer (score 4):

Немного дополню [ответ от @MarianD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1129035/217579):

График нормального распределения вероятности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из графика видно, что:

- с вероятностью `68.3%` значения попадают в интервал `[-1, 1]`
- с вероятностью `95.5%` значения попадают в интервал `[-2, 2]`
- с вероятностью `99.7%` значения попадают в интервал `[-3, 3]`

  ---

**Практический пример:**

Cоздаем 1D тензор, состоящий из 1.000.000 элементов и смотрим какие получились минимум и максимум:

```
In [18]: import torch

In [19]: a = torch.randn(10**6)

In [20]: a.min()
Out[20]: tensor(-5.0071)

In [21]: a.max()
Out[21]: tensor(5.4262)
```

Comment: Красиво, даже примеры больших чисел, спасибо. (+1, конечно).

Comment: @MarianD, спасибо! Я подумал, что практический пример поможет понять как работает функция `torch.randn`)

Comment: А как построить график нормального распределения, созданного PyTorch?

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, советую открыть новый вопрос, содержащий [mcve]